# How to configure pub sub for multiple subscribers with Rhino Service Bus?

Tags: rhino, servicebus

I am trying to set up pub-sub between 1 publisher and multiple subscribers using Rhino Service Bus. However, all I ever seem to get is competing consumers (where messges are distributed between 1 consumer or the other, but not sent to both).

My current publisher configuration looks like this (Note: I'm using the new OnewayRhinoServiceBusFacility so I don't need to define a bus element in the sender)

```
<facility id="rhino.esb.sender" >
        <messages>
            <add name="My.Messages.Namespace" endpoint="msmq://localhost/my.queue"/>
        </messages>
</facility>
```

My current subscriber configuration looks like this:

```
<facility id="rhino.esb.receiver" >
    <bus threadCount="1" numberOfRetries="5" endpoint="msmq://localhost/my.queue" DisableAutoQueueCreation="false" />
    <messages>
        <add name="My.Messages.Namespace" endpoint="msmq://localhost/my.queue" />
    </messages>
</facility>
```

I have 2 simple command line apps which start up publisher and subscriber. I just copy and paste subscriber bin to set up 2 subscribers. My message handler looks like this:

```
public class DummyReceiver : ConsumerOf<MyMessageType>
{
    public void Consume(MyMessageType message)
    {
                    // ......
            }
    }
```

Any ideas? Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! Was using Send instead of Publish in my producer code. Had copied it from another example and forgot to change.

So, for reference my publisher code is like this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter("RhinoEsbSettings.xml"));
RhinoServiceBusFacility facility = new RhinoServiceBusFacility();
container.Kernel.AddFacility("rhino.esb", facility);

var bus = container.Resolve<IStartableServiceBus>();
bus.Start();

MyMessageType msg = new ...
bus.Publish(msg);
```

And my consumer startup code is like this:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter("RhinoEsbSettings.xml"));
container.Register(Component.For<ConsumerOf<MyMessageType>>().ImplementedBy<DummyReceiver>().LifeStyle.Transient.Named("Consumer"));

RhinoServiceBusFacility facility = new RhinoServiceBusFacility();
container.Kernel.AddFacility("rhino.esb", facility);

var bus = container.Resolve<IStartableServiceBus>();
bus.Start();
```